# jQuery get data-id from selector onchange

Tags: jquery, selector, custom-data-attribute

Is it possible to get the data attribute value during an on change event?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.mystatus').on("change", function() {
    var value = this.value;
    alert(value);

    var myid = get the value of data-myid
    // myid should equal '123'
  });
});
```

```html
<select class="mystatus" data-myid="123">
  <option value="No Status">No Status</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="Potential">Potential</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yes, I know that it works on each option.   I'm asking how to get it from the select definition - to the right of the class?

Comment: *Is it possible to get the data attribute value during an on change event?* - yes, your code does that.   If you're asking something else, then please include what you're *actually* asking in the question, not as a comment or a code comment

Comment: [This post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425359/jquery-datatable-add-row-content-with-link) on Meta looks like it belongs here, not there. Can you repost it?

Comment: And that Meta post would be answered with this solution: [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the data attribute exists on the `<select>`, access the data atribute using: `$(this).data`.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.mystatus').on('change', function() {
    var $select = $(this);
  
    var value = $select.val();
    console.log(value);

    var selectDataId = $select.data('myid');
    console.log(selectDataId);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="mystatus" data-myid="123" required>
  <option value="" selected disabled>-- Choose and option --</option>
  <option value="No Status">No Status</option>
  <option value="Potential">Potential</option>
</select>
```